# iterate through Poco::JSON::Object in insertion order

Tags: json, poco-libraries

It is possible to preserve insertion order when parsing a JSON struct with a
`Poco::JSON::Parser( new Poco::JSON::ParseHandler( true ) )`: the non-default `ParseHandler` parameter `preserveObjectOrder = true` is handed over to the `Poco::JSON::Object`s so that they keep an private list of keys sorted in insertion order. 
An object can then be serialized via `Object::stringify()` to look just like the source JSON string. 
Fine.

What, however, is the official way to step through a `Poco::JSON::Object` and access its internals in insertion order? `Object::getNames()` and `begin()`/`end()` use the alphabetical order of keys, not insertion order -- is there another way to access the values, or do I have to patch Poco?

Answer (score 1):

As you already said:

- Poco::JSON::ParseHandler goes into the Poco::JSON::Parser-constructor.
- Poco::JSON::Parser::parse() creates a Poco::Dynamic::Var.
- From that you'll *extract* a Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr.
- The Poco::JSON:Object has the method "getNames". Beginning with [this commit](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/pull/2145/files#diff-fea33b4108b39abc8f33959720e40fbdR145) it seems to preserve the order, if it was requested via the ParseHandler. ([Poco::JSON:Object::getNames 1.8.1](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.8.1-release/JSON/src/Object.cpp#L137), [Poco::JSON:Object::getNames 1.9.0](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.9.0-release/JSON/src/Object.cpp#L150))

So now it should work as expected to use:

```
for(auto const & name : object->getNames()){
    auto const & value = object->get(name);  // or one of the other get-methods
    // ... do things ...
}
```

Comment: are you sure about that? It's not clear from the link that that is the case, code has been added in this area but are you sure that is what it does?